# Error while updating XML Attribute Python minidom

Tags: xml, python-2.7, minidom

Hello I am trying to update an attribute `NumberOfArg` value in the following XML using Python minidom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BootUpdaterGenerator OffsetImagesAddress="0x15000">
  <!--Offset of Images Start Address (0xXX hexa, XX decimal)-->
  <Locations>
    <!--All Locations are relative to PIS parameter-->
    <S19MapPath Name="out\code">
      <!--Relative Path of .s19 and .map file-->
    </S19MapPath>
    <CnfPath Name="work\bsw\products\cnf\icsp_lifm\i">
      <!--Relative Path of icsp_lifm_cnf.arxml file-->
    </CnfPath>
    <BuildDirPath Name="work\config\builddescription">
      <!--Relative Path of builddescription.xml file-->
    </BuildDirPath>
    <CksCalcXmlPath Name="work\config\ckscalc\ckscalc_0b0.xml">
      <!--Relative Full Path of ckscalc.xml file-->
    </CksCalcXmlPath>
    <ToolsDrive Name="A">
      <!--Drive location for CKS_Calc and SignCalc-->
    </ToolsDrive>
  </Locations>
  <SizeCoherencies>
    <BootManager Size="0xF">
      <!--Size of BootManager Coherency (0xXX hexa, XX decimal)-->
    </BootManager>
    <BootLoader Size="0x24">
      <!--Size of BootLoader Coherency (0xXX hexa, XX decimal)-->
    </BootLoader>
  </SizeCoherencies>
  <Sign_Tool Command="signcalc.exe" Path="A:\deltools\signcalc\12" Arg1=".\ckscalc_u.xml" Arg2="-L" NumberOfArg="1" />
  <Options Checksum="yes" Signature="no" DeleteEmptyPage="no" DeleteEmptyPageSize="250" ImagesId="1">
    <!--Checksum : "yes" or "no" depending on whether CKS_CALC on Output File is required or not-->
    <!--Signature (not implemented) : "yes" or "no" depending on whether Signature on Output File is required or not-->
    <!--DeleteEmptyPage : "yes" or "no" depending on whether Empty Pages have to be deleted from images or not-->
    <!--DeleteEmptyPageSize : "value" size of Empty Page for deletion (0xXX hexa, XX decimal)-->
    <!--ImagesId : Images loaded in BootUpdater : 1 : BootLoader, 2 : BootManager + BootLoader, 3 : HSM-->
  </Options>
</BootUpdaterGenerator>
```

This is what I did so far:

```
rootNode = xml.dom.minidom.parse(buGeneratorXmlFile)
collection = rootNode.documentElement
signToolNode = collection.getElementsByTagName('Sign_Tool')
att = signToolNode[0].attributes.getNamedItem('NumberOfArg')
att.value = 2
#Update file
with open('test', "w") as f:
    rootNode.writexml(f, encoding='UTF-8')
```

But I get following error for writexml:

```
AttributeError: "'int' object has no attribute 'replace'"
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem! The `att.value` had to be set as str and not as int so `att.value = '2'` works :)